# How to access class fields for dynamically called class in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript2.4

I am trying to access fields of multiple components inside main component class using function Array.

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component.js';
import { SrcComponent } from './src.component.js';

const components = [AppComponent, SrcComponent];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: components,
    entryComponents: components
})

export class AppModule {
    modName: any = null;
    constructor() {
        this.getModuleName(components);
    }
    getModuleName(srcCom: any[]) {
        var myVar = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < srcCom.length; i++) {
            myVar = srcCom[i];
            // Here I am trying to access fields from different componet
            this.title = myVar.title;
            this.modName = myVar._moduleName;
            console.log(myVar);
        }
        console.log(myVar);
        return srcCom;
    }
    ngDoBootstrap(appref: ApplicationRef) {
        appref.bootstrap(AppComponent);
        appref.bootstrap(SrcComponent);
    }
}
```

**Component class**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'new-app',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public _moduleName: string = null;
    constructor() {
        this._moduleName = 'App-Component';
    }
    title = 'App';
}
```

**second component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'new-app1',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`
})
export class SrcComponent {
    public _moduleName: string = null;
    constructor() {
        this._moduleName = 'Src-Component';
    }
    title = 'Source';
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you have an error? If so, please could you post it?

Comment: Not an error, I am not able to access fields title or _moduleName from @NgModule inside AppModule class.

Comment: `// Here I am trying to access fields from different componet` <= Why?? The components have not yet been instantiated. The module serves as a manifest of components, services, etc. that are used by it or "belong" to it. You can also do some basic configuration in the module for the types that are associated with it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your swift reply. I am not getting properly as per your above statement. Could you please suggest some working example code. that would be helpful for me to understand properly.